# Positioning the counter, More logic than coding

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to make the users to select a maximum of 4 toppings. Pressing a button they will change the color of the button and add it to a list which will be displayed.Also, the user can delete the topping by pressing again on the same button. I managed to get all of these sorted, the problem is that when the user adds the last topping and the program does not allow him to delete it anymore. I was changing constantly the position of the if statement or the counter but nothing. I presume is a logic problem however I could not find it. Please give me a hand

```
private void labelTuna_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (counter < 4)
        {
            if (!My_Pizza.Items.Contains(tuna))
            {
                My_Pizza.Items.Add(tuna);
                labelTuna.BackColor = Color.Green;
                counter++;
            }
            else
            {
                My_Pizza.Items.Remove(tuna);
                labelTuna.BackColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
                counter--;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have more than 4 toppings, Remove then replace one");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just make your code work this will do.

```
if ( counter >= 4 && !My_Pizza.Items.Contains(tuna) )
{
    MessageBox.Show("You have more than 4 toppings, Remove then replace one");
{
else    
{
    if (!My_Pizza.Items.Contains(tuna))
    {
        My_Pizza.Items.Add(tuna);
        labelTuna.BackColor = Color.Green;
        counter++;
    }
    else
    {
        My_Pizza.Items.Remove(tuna);
        labelTuna.BackColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
        counter--;
    }
}
```

Your error was not to check if one of the topping preset was the tuna.

Having said that the code is a bit messy even.

You don't need the counter variable, just check My_Pizza.Items.Count

And also as you have written the program you need to write almost duplicate code for each topping.

A function with a parameter will be better.